# Using android apps on Windows Phone

Tags: apk, windows-10-mobile, xap

Hello to the Community,
   What I want is that can I somehow unpack the APK file and convert it so that I can make it work on Windows Phone.(And I am not talking about Project Astoria)

Comment: You need to include more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: no, this is not possible. you need to ask the developer to develop the app in Xamarin to create iOS, Android and Win10 UWP app from the same codebase

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft no longer supports running android apps on windows phone.  In the early betas for windows 10 mobile it had an android subsystem which allowed this but it was removed.